# Is there an easy to use and well maintained split & multivariate testing library for PHP?

Tags: php, testing, multivariate-testing

Google Web Optimizer is great, but I don't like the idea of depending upon JavaScript for split testing let alone multivariate testing. I'm looking for a fairly simple and well maintained testing library for php.

Does anyone know if a testing library exists?

Open source and/or free is a plus, but as long as its worth the money commercial software will do.

Split testing and multivariate testing is where a number of different pages (split testing), or a single page with different sections are split between visitors of a site, a specific or set of actions on the users part are chosen as a conversion, and it calculates based on numbers of users and conversions which page, or section is best.

See http://www.google.com/websiteoptimizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this
http://www.phpscenario.org/
It seems to be somewhat well maintained. I'll try it out and see if it fits my needs.

Comment: Doesn't yet support multivariate testing.

Answer (score -3):

Try PHPUnit

http://phpunit.sourceforge.net/

OK, then now understanding your question.  The answer is its impossible to do this with just PHP.  You're wanting to do user interface testing based on the back end language, it just doesn't make any sense.  You are dependent upon javascript, because javascript is the front end language available to you.  Why don't you want to depend on Javascript?

Comment: I'm looking for a different kind of testing ;)

Comment: @yoda Edited the question to elaborate on multivariate testing.